# Can not connect R to download packages

Tags: r

```
I am trying to conect to download a few packages for R. However I find the following problem:

utils:::menuInstallPkgs() 
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
task: From R main ledger I select : packages/installpackages I get

Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.es.r-project.org/src/contrib
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib
Error in install.packages(NULL, .libPaths()[1L], dependencies = NA, type = type) : 
no packages were specified
Además: Warning message:
In open.connection(con, "r") :
no fue posible conectarse a 'cran.r-project.org' en el puerto 80.
```

So it seems that R can not conect through a port. I have run the following checks - I go to task manager / File / Run new task / in create new task I write cmd and press enter and get the command Prompt and type "netstat - aon | more" and press enter, then I see the detail of IP ports per running aplication and can not find any file for R (as per this open). Also I can not find it in the task manager / services, the R application.

Is there any way to be able to connect R so I can download packages.

Comment: You may be behind a restrictive firewall, in which case you may need to install packages by hand.

Comment: Is not the case as when the firewall is deactivated it also occurs

Comment: Please read: ?internet2

Comment: > ?internet2
No documentation for ‘internet2’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??internet2’                                                                        > ??internet2 
starting httpd help server ...Error in startDynamicHelp(TRUE) : unable to create socket will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a chance to this approach that always work for me

```
setRepositories()
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: that means that you are implemmenting several repositories, including Bioconductor, at the same time. be sure to leave a empty space between numbers

Comment: Thanks however the issue appears to be that I can not get R to conect to anywhere.  When implementing what you suggest I get "Error: unexpected numeric constant in "1 2" "

Comment: @ it is specific to the R versions following 2.15 basically I can not access packages help or anything.